cv_bridge.h not found ROS2
I need cv_bridge on my cmakelist.txt. Cmakelist shows a path for cv_bridge.h, however there is no file on that name at that path.
I have opencv 4.5.4,ros2 humble.
I tried to install cv_bridge by following this however, cmake still looks at another path.
What do I need to fix this problem?
Cmakelist.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(synchroniz_wo)

# Find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(sensor_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(cv_bridge REQUIRED) 
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(pcl_conversions REQUIRED)
find_package(PCL REQUIRED)
find_package(message_filters REQUIRED)

# Include directories
include_directories(
  include
  ${rclcpp_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${sensor_msgs_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${cv_bridge_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${message_filters_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${pcl_conversions_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

# Add the executable
add_executable(synchroniz_wo ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/synchroniz_wo.cpp)

# Link libraries
target_link_libraries(synchroniz_wo
  ${rclcpp_LIBRARIES}
  ${sensor_msgs_LIBRARIES}
  ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
  ${cv_bridge_LIBRARIES}
  ${PCL_LIBRARIES}
  ${message_filters_LIBRARIES}
  ${pcl_conversions_LIBRARIES}
)

# Output information for debugging
message(STATUS "CV Bridge Include Directory: ${cv_bridge_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "CV Bridge Library: ${cv_bridge_LIBRARIES}")

# Install the executable
install(TARGETS synchroniz_wo
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})

ament_package()

The error when I run make command:
synchroniz_wo.cpp:13:10: fatal error: cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h: No such file or directory
   13 | #include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>

The path:
-- CV Bridge Include Directory: 

/usr/include/opencv4;/opt/ros/humble/include/sensor_msgs
-- CV Bridge Library: opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_stitching;opencv_video...etc.


Something like this usually works for me:
ament_target_dependencies(synchronize_wo cv_bridge)

When using ament_target_dependencies you should not have to explicitly list the include and library files. Also not when you use target_link_libraries(synchronize_wo cv_bridge::cv_bridge)

Oh, and make sure to also look for cv_bridge.hpp . The suffix has changed recently.
